# Why do I have a "Cannot read property 'top' of undefined" error when I try to do this animation using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text document,(about 3500 lines of HTML), in which I have some JavaScript in the  that will take input and highlight the word. This part of the process works fine and I have no problems with it.

The problem happens when I take that input and try to have the highlighted element scroll to the top of the container.  I have tried this on two files one being plain text,(no HTML tags other than `<p>`,`<body>`,`<html>`), in this file it works well and everything scrolls as it should.

The problem happens when I use the same script on another file,( the one I mentioned above),the highlight function is fine but the Jquery scroll will not function as it should.  I have taken all the whitespace out (to match the text file),no change.  In the text file I added new lines, still worked fine, but as soon as I added some tags like, h1, strong, br, this is when the error was thrown.

I get the same error every time I try to run it and that is :

> Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

The script:

```
<script>
/**  scroll to element function **/

    function scrollToElement(selector, time, verticalOffset) {
        time = typeof (time) != 'undefined' ? time : 500;
        verticalOffset = typeof (verticalOffset) != 'undefined' ? verticalOffset : 0;
        element = $(selector);
        offset = element.offset();
        offsetTop = offset.top + verticalOffset; //Error here
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: offsetTop
        }, time);
    }

    /**document ready**/
    $(document).ready(function () {
        count = 0;

        /* scroll to 200px before highlighted word with animation time of 500ms */
        $('#next').click(function (e) {
            if (count < $('MARK').length) {
                count++;
            } else {
                count = 1;
             }
            e.preventDefault();
            scrollToElement('MARK:nth-child(' + count + ')', 500, -200);
        });
        $('#prev').click(function (e) {
            if (count > 1) {
                count--;
            } else {
                count = $('MARK').length;
              }
            e.preventDefault();
            scrollToElement('MARK:nth-child(' + count + ')', 500, -200);
        })
    });

</script>
```

The line that triggers the error is `offsetTop = offset.top + verticalOffset;`
Why is this error happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: Try replacing `offset = element.offset();` with `offset = $(selector).offset();`

Comment: @depperm thanks for the edit, was unsure as to how to add code.

Comment: Does the 2nd page also have `MARK` elements on it?

Comment: Use the `var` keyword when declaring variables..

Comment: @Lal Thanks for the effort but alas the same result :(

Comment: Check if selector has value in it,. @Tom

Comment: If u can please reproduce the issue in a fiddle and share the link with us..

Comment: @Stryner The 2nd page like the 1st is using the <MARK> tag only to add the highlight to the word/s entered as input, there are no other words with mark tags in either doc. And as I say the whole thing works fine in the first doc the highlight and scroll.

Comment: @Lal sorry for the delay in responding.  Selector has a value yes, it is selector = "MARK:nth-child(in here is the "index value?" of the search value 1,2,3,etc.)  To reproduce, very easy I used the Lorem ipsum  text.  Without tags the scroll will work but as soon as you add some tags the it throws an error.

Comment: Can you explain why you are using "MARK:nth-child(' + count + ')" and not "MARK[count]" ?